# What to report with the Kruskal Wallis?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, reporting

I am analyzing a dataset, where I have 3 categories (independent variable), and one continuous value (dependent variable). I am studying if the continuous value is significantly different between the three groups. I have 65 values in each category. The 3 groups are homoscedastic, but the dependent variable is not normal in any of the groups. I currently use a Kruskal-Wallis test, with the Dunn's test for post-hoc comparisons, where the p value is adjusted with a Benjamini Hochberg correction.

What should I report in such a test?